Earliest time for Maariv on Tisha b'Av
This year (2024) Tisha b'Av begins on the evening of August 12. In my locale, Plag on August 12 will be at 7:11 pm, and Shkia will be at 8:39 pm.  The fast, of course, begins at sundown (8:39 pm).
If it is the usual custom of a community to daven Maariv right after plag, is that permissible on Tisha b'Av? Or is it necessary to wait until the 8th of Av is "fully complete" before davening Maariv?  In particular, can the reading of Eicha start before Shkia?

Eicha can always be read later

Even if early prayer is permitted, that would cause the fast to start early, which most people (at reasonable latitudes) would probably not appreciate

@DoubleAA is the beginning of the fast triggered by Maariv, even if it is before sunset?

you haven't asked that in this post, but AFAIK yes the fast starts early with arvit, just like shabbat starts early with arvit

This is my understanding
There is no need to wait until night any differently than on any other night of the year. Reading of eicha is a custom without stipulation to have to be read at night.
If it were necessary to wait until night the commentaries would have pointed that out similar to shavuot, first night of pesach, megilah on purim etc.
